# Is T-mobile iPhone 6 unlocked

Tags: unlock, iphone

I bought an iPhone 6 T-mobile from Apple store. I tried my SIM from Sweden and it worked. However tried with another SIM from Ghana but it didn't work, showing "no service".

Does that mean the phone is locked or something else is wrong?

Comment: what do you mean by "same SIM from Ghana", same as what?

Comment: Sorry i tried with another SIM from Ghana but it didn't work. I just tried with a 3rd SIM card and it worked :) This confirms it is unlocked

Comment: when you bought it, it should have been clearly labelled as to whether it was locked or not. Provider sticker, locked, otherwise not. Apple Store sells both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "no service" can have other reasons than the SIM card and iPhone lock.

Since it worked in Sweden (with non T-Mobile SIM) then the iPhone is unlocked.

Try another provider or better try a prepay SIM to see if that works in Ghana.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if your sim card is active by the operator.
2. Try sim card from other Ghana Operator.
3. Try other sim from the same operator.